# Scanner is reading numbers wrong from Standard IO. Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
    unos[i].x = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(unos[i].x);
    unos[i].R = input.nextFloat();
    System.out.println(unos[i].R);
}
```

If I input 2.177, unos[i].x will be 2177.0, which it clearly isn't. If I input 3.15, it will give me Input Mismatch Exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your locale interprets `.` as a thousands-separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If I input 2.177, unos[i].x will be 2177.0*

well this is because you are reading doubles with a locale where decimal part is with coma instead of dot.

YOU have to tell the scanner how to read the decimal part...

I mean, set the locale

## Example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
unos[i].x = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println(unos[i].x);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you, but I should be reading Doubles. 2.177 is a double and I need unos[i].x to be 2.177, not 2177.0. unos[] is an array of Unos class and Unos.x and Unos.R are both doubles.

Comment: Now I updated the answer... the Locale is the reason of the problem... take a look and let me know...

Answer (score 0):

`InputMismatchException` while reading `Double` numbers with `Scanner` can be caused by your locale settings. In some countries, default decimal separator is comma instead of dot. Try setting the US locale for your scanner:

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```